# Introducing daily standup meeting to workplace without standup meeting tradition

Tags: management, project-management

To have a better understanding of the project status and a better relationship with the  developers who report to me, I want to introduce daily standup meeting ( [as per suggested](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/a/5957/979)) to the developers in my office, but the problem is that this is never a part of our culture, and I afraid that introducing this, they would think that the management wants to "spy on them".

Currently, how do we work [is as thus](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/5940/how-to-measure-the-creative-workers-output-who-are-not-filling-in-the-timesheet):

1. Define Road Map for my product under development using Redmine. And I define the tasks that should go into each Road Map. The date for a Road Map is fixed ( Usually on a monthly basis) and usually, One sprint per Road Map.
2. After that, I assign the tasks to the developers and ask them to provide estimation for each task. After looking at their estimation, I will either take out or put in more tasks for a particular sprint so that they don't over-commit and can't deliver in the end.
3. I ask them to fill in the amount of time worked on a specific task everyday and the percentage of the progress so that I can keep track of the progress.
4. I would review their progresses at the beginning of every week to see whether I need to move some tasks to the next sprint.

Clearly, as you can see from my question [here](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/5940/how-to-measure-the-creative-workers-output-who-are-not-filling-in-the-timesheet), the above process isn't working fine. So I am thinking about introducing daily standup meeting, but I fear the developers would take it to mean that I am spying on them, and hence some bad blood may run.

## Question:

**How to introduce daily standup meeting in this case?**

Comment: Hi Graviton, great question, but what do you mean in your title by "old workplace"? Can you clarify?

Comment: @jmort253, I've updated the question as per requested.

Comment: I think, it's a very interesting question. But why do you think it would be a kind of "spying" on them? If you take those daily meetings leisurely, such as just a short conversation, do you think it would have the same feeling?

Comment: When everyone has to be in the office at a certain time and stand up to talk about the their progress as a result of a change of policy, such suspicion will surely linger.

Comment: IMO, it would fit better @ [PMSE](http://pm.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @TiagoCardoso it wouldn't hurt to mention that as PMSE moderator, your opinion about this carries some authority :)

Comment: @gnat I didn't mention it on purpose to avoid biasing any other opinion. I believe that if we have some upvotes on my comment, means that the community agrees and we can think of migrating the question.

Comment: The daily stand-up is only part of larger process. It allows the team to become aware of problems as they arise and before the problems become show-stoppers. However, if the process (roadmap, tasks, progress estimation, etc) is totally dysfunctional, the stand-up will simply serve to make that clear to everyone. In other words, if the process itself needs fixing, the standup alone can't do that.

Comment: How do you measure the "percentage of progress" on a task?  In software development, rarely is there a way to correlate the time taken to reach the current state to the time required to complete the task. I once had a project manager who tried to operate this way, and didn't understand that the final 20% of the work (by feature count, bug fix count, etc.) could take 50% of the time to complete - or that an unexpected bump in the road could set one back several days or more.

Comment: @alroc, yes unsophisticated usage of %-completed is a MAJOR red-flag for an impending train-wreck with stakeholders/management.

Comment: Hey Graviton, normally we discourage cross-posting, but in this case, we really feel like your question fits both [Project Management SE](http://pm.stackexchange.com) as well as Workplace SE. Feel free to post this on PMSE as well and make any edits that might be needed to address project managers.

Comment: A daily standup without any of the other things that usually go with it (Agile) can end up being a huge waste of time. If your org then sometime decides to try Agile, everyone will say "standups - they are a huge waste of time" and you will end up making things harder in the long run.

Comment: Couldn't you just say, 'If you have any actionable items/road blocks/problems - come speak to me' and save everyone a lot of time?  If you have six team members, five of them are going to be awfully bored while the six tells you they are 'blocked by X'.  Rarely is that information relevant to the group, IMHO, and seems like it would be more effective to handle it on a 'as needed' basis, with the people who are impacted.

Answer (score 10):

One tip which might make the team feel that the standup is for their benefit, not just yours:

Traditionally, in the daily standup, everyone says:

- What they did yesterday
- What they are planning to do today
- Whether there are any impediments or stumbling blocks

If you put the most emphasis on the *third* of those items, it might make it clearer that the daily standup is about keeping things running smoothly, not just about keeping the manager informed. I can't count how many times someone has said, in a standup, that they were having a problem in such-and-such bit of code, and someone else has instantly said "oh yeah, I've had that problem before, I can help you out". Particularly with larger teams, it really helps make the connection between people working on a particular area and other people who are familiar with it from past work.

Beyond that, as Darhazer said, it's a common mistake to turn the daily standup to status report to the manager, not to the team. If people are facing you and talking to you at the standup, nudge them with a gentle reminder that they are here to talk to their teammates, not to you.

And lastly, make sure that you also use the standup to tell them what *you* have achieved yesterday and plan to achieve today! If those things are connected to resolving the impediments and stumbling blocks that developers reported in previous standups, so much the better!!

Comment: RE: Impediments/stumbling blocks, it also helps call out particular tasks that are blocking others' tasks, so maybe that particular developer doesn't realize he's blocking 3 people from continuing with their work until he finishes that class he's been having trouble with, but the other devs don't understand he's having trouble with it, just getting annoyed it's not yet done. Basically 3 devs "task 123, 124, 125 is waiting on 122 to get finished. John how's that looking?" John: "I'm having trouble getting x to work." Other devs "lets get together after this...

Comment: Great point Randy, I was totally thinking of external impediments but of course there can be ones internal to the team also, and a good standup should help in getting them moving

Comment: +1 - " not just about keeping the manager informed" Management reporting should be a by-product of the data included in the tools to make it easier for someone to get things done.

Comment: @Randy — Why would a stand-up meeting be needed for that? When a worker Alice needs something that is being done by a worker Bob, naturally Alice goes to Bob and asks about the thing. Then asking "Can I help you with this thing?" is a matter of team spirit, and has to be encouraged by the employer.

Answer (score 9):

When you introduce a new practice, you have to start with the **why**. Why daily standup? What the developer has to say on this. Why he have to say it. One common mistake is to talk at the daily standup the same things you can already see in Redmine. Or to turn the daily standup to status report to the manager, not to the team. The daily standup have to be between team members and should answer the question why this task is not going the way I was thinking it will go yesterday. It should not be finished/not finished report, unless someone needs to know if this is finished or not (but usually a tool like redmine can tell this). And you have to be prepared - and explain this to the team - that they will fail to use the standup meeting properly and you have to coach them.

Answer (score 3):

IMHO, without embracing the **spirit** of Agile (for example, in Agile world you do not assign the tasks to the developers) this wouldn't work; it will become аnother status meeting (and participants will have to stand instead of sitting for the sake of ritual).

Comment: The purpose of standing is to keep the meetings brief; assignemnt of tasks by the OP is done elsewhere.

Comment: @JeffO: thanks, I already know this secret. By the way, there is more than one way to keep mettings short. **assignemnt of tasks by the OP is done elsewhere** in SCRUM environment it's done by the team, not OP

Comment: I've had this issue with a group that tried to do this. These daily standups required 10 or so people to get in a room, and they often lasted for 30-60 minutes. It ended up such a waste of time for most of us that we finally got our managers to nix it in favor of something else.

Comment: @Shauna : that's exactly what I was talking about - people are trying to use ***rituals*** from Scrum without accepting **core values** of the Agile methodology. It's funny to see how my reply has been voted up and down quite a few times ;)

Answer (score 2):

In the context of this question (and your previous one) daily stand-up meetings and sprints can form part of the [Scrum](http://scrumalliance.org/pages/scrum_101) approach to [Agile](http://www.agilealliance.org/) software development.

We were starting to look at Agile, then ended up hiring an experienced software engineer who guided us through the initial 18 months of getting a full-blown Scrum system set up.  Now, no-one would go back, but this was a huge change in our culture and was hugely challenging.

Standups formed a part of this cultural shift from the outset;  in fact they were the simplest part of Scrum to get into play.  This video from [Atlassian](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=COsbE0guM7I) summed it up.  They used to have a whole series on the website, which were very good.

My experience is that, as a line manager, its also very tough.  "Letting go" and learning to coach, guide and trust your team is very hard.

While "stand-ups" are important, the key is the retrospective meetings, and asking ***the team*** to honestly take ownership of their own short comings and address them.

So - to sum up, we adopted stand-ups as part of a drive towards a formal scrum process.  This was led from (some of) the team, and as a (non-developer) manager I had to educate myself very rapidly on the implications.  We progressed to scrum master certification for the majority of the team.

Compared to where we were, I can only describe the process as transformational.  We're a more productive, happier team as a result.

Comment: Who, "we"? You talk like Louis the Eleventh.